# Weather from yesterday

Tags: json

I would like to get everyday of the weather from yesterday with darksky, but how do I set this up? Because the `UnixTime` is based on date, but the only thing I would like is the following data from yesterday, not hourly, daily is just fine:

Is use this from the `API`:

```
GET https://api.darksky.net/forecast/{key}/52.1038,5.1909?exclude=currently,flags,hourly&lang=nl&units=auto
```

Here you can read the documentation:
https://darksky.net/dev/docs/time-machine

```
{
    "time":1502575200,
    "summary":"Licht bewolkt vanaf de middag, houdt aan tot de avond.",
    "icon":"partly-cloudy-day",
    "sunriseTime":1502598072,
    "sunsetTime":1502651386,
    "moonPhase":0.69,
    "precipIntensity":0.0178,
    "precipIntensityMax":0.1245,
    "precipIntensityMaxTime":1502618400,
    "precipProbability":0.13,
    "precipType":"rain",
    "temperatureMin":13.25,
    "temperatureMinTime":1502596800,
    "temperatureMax":21.37,
    "temperatureMaxTime":1502640000,
    "apparentTemperatureMin":13.25,
    "apparentTemperatureMinTime":1502596800,
    "apparentTemperatureMax":21.37,
    "apparentTemperatureMaxTime":1502640000,
    "dewPoint":12.9,
    "humidity":0.76,
    "windSpeed":0.47,
    "windGust":4.88,
    "windGustTime":1502658000,
    "windBearing":12,
    "cloudCover":0.27,
    "pressure":1019.62,
    "ozone":303.52,
    "uvIndex":4,
    "uvIndexTime":1502618400
}
```

Comment: but what if you have half of the day sun and the other half of the day rain? what would you show? Sun or rain?

Answer (score 0):

From their documentation for request parameters:

> Either be a UNIX time (that is, seconds since midnight GMT on 1 Jan 1970) or a string formatted as follows: `[YYYY]-[MM]-[DD]T[HH]:[MM]:[SS][timezone]`.

The easiest way would be to subtract 86400 (the number of seconds in a day) from the current UNIX timestamp. This will give you yesterday's UNIX timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

The API sends through `daily` information in the response. https://darksky.net/dev/docs/response You can get this data using any *time* value on a given day.

Days are `86400` second long and so subtracting or adding multiples of this number will allow you to change the date.

The API also allows a string formatted as `[YYYY]-[MM]-[DD]T[HH]:[MM]:[SS][timezone]`. You could use this format instead for readability if it is easier.